# Matching express recursive pattern

Tags: node.js, express

Well, after almost hour of investigation I have to admit I am lost with some basic routing in express 4.
I have a very simple application which is dealing only with nested resources. I have successfully implemented api match as follow:

```
app.get('/api/:resource*', function(request, response) { ... }
```

All I need, is basically match any other regexp. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you simply say what Urls you are using, and what results you want?

Comment: Url would be a tree based (like science/chemistry/organicChemistry) its depth could be from 1 up to n. And the result should be embarrassingly response.render(CONSTANT_PAGE)

Comment: OK, I've figured out what was wrong. The problem is not the routing but serving a static content via express middleware.

Comment: What did you actually do to solve it @MirekSurma